CocoaPods Error After Adding Widget Extension in React Native 0.72 Project
I'm encountering an error after adding a widget extension to my React Native project (version 0.72) for iOS. The app was working fine before adding the widget, but after integrating it, pod install throws an error related to CocoaPods.

What I’ve Tried:
I added inherit! :search_paths to the ProductExtension target.
Tried removing use_frameworks! :linkage => :static.
Checked if all Pods in the main app are compatible with static frameworks.
Updated CocoaPods to the latest version and ran pod install again.
Environment:
React Native version: 0.72
CocoaPods version: 1.15.2

what's the error?

Could you tell me the error so that I can more accurately understand ?

I have attached the error when running the pod install command
